# Python Flask and AJAX - Update progress bar during python method

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I have a python method which is checking a number of given devices for some information and then presenting the information on a web interface using Flask. That's all working fine but it takes a couple of seconds for each device to be accessed, searched etc. Therefore I would like a progress bar which displays the number of devices that have finished out of the total.

I assume AJAX would be used for this, but having never used AJAX before I'm a bit lost. Can someone point me in the right direction?